# Вызывается деструктор в перегрузке оператора

Tags: c++

Получил такую проблему - не знаю как исправить.
Есть следующий код:

```
Foo& operator+(const Foo& other)
{
   Foo result(this._field + other._field);
   return result;
}
```

В классе  есть поле-указатель, соответственно в конструкторе оно инициализируется через new, в деструкторе удаляется через delete. И вот в чем проблема: по завершению работы оператора вызывается деструктор для result! ну и понятно, что в месте типа Foo foo = A + B; (где A и В тоже понятно Foo) деструктор вызовется еще раз. Получаю 2 высвобождение.

Comment: Кто нибудь может объяснить, за что (или зачем?) минусуют подобные вопросы? (вопрос, конечно,  риторический, при нынешнем движке его почти никто не увидит)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мой хрустальный шар говорит, что вы забыли определить конструктор копирования.

При этом у вас вызывается конструктор копирования по умолчанию, который просто копирует все поля, в том числе и умирающий указатель. Чтобы всё было правильно, вы должны в конструкторе копирования аллоцировать *новые* данные, а не присвоить тот же указатель, иначе при смерти одного из объектов данные в другом будут испорчены.

Деструктор для `result` будет вызван, ведь вы размещаете его на стеке, в фрейме, который умирает. С другой стороны, умный компилятор со включенной оптимизацией скорее всего произведёт copy elision, и выкинет ненужное копирование.

---

Если вы пользуетесь современным компилятором C++, эффективнее было бы определить ещё и конструктор перемещения. (Но это не отменяет необходимости конструктора копирования.)

---

Не забывайте, что кроме копирующего конструктора вам надо определить оператор присваивания. Освежите в памяти «[правило большой тройки](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)» (или пятёрки, применительно к C++11).

Comment: Да, спасибо. Если честно, это был чужой ужаснейший код, автор которого меня убедил, что конструктор копирования есть, только где-то глубоко=)

Comment: Сила хрустального шара!!!!!

Answer (score 4):

Ваша функция возвращает ссылку на локальную переменную. Локальная переменная уничтожается при выходе из функции и ссылка остается указывать в никуда. Это не может и не будет работать в принципе, какие конструкторы вы ни определяйте.

Вы, очевидно, пытаетесь реализовать бинарный оператор `+`. Такой оператор должен возвращать результат по значению, а не по ссылке.

Comment: Да, уже переписал и создал объект в куче

Comment: @АлексейСаровский: Не обязательно создавать объект в куче (это скорее всего приведёт к утечке памяти), просто возвращайте по значению. `Foo operator+(const Foo& other)` (без первого `&`).

Comment: @Алексей Саровский: В куче? Не видя всего кода трудно судить об осмысленности такого решения, но скорее всего это закончится утечкой памяти. Не надо создавать объект в куче. Просто напишите правильные конструкторы и возвращайте объект *по значению*.